# How to find only the first and last line of a file using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file called `error_log` for the apache and I want to see the first line and the last line of this file using `sed` command. Would you please help me how can I do that?

I know how to do that with `head` and `tail` commands, but I'm curious if it's possible in `sed` command too.

I have read the `man sed` and have googled a lot but nothing is found unfortunately.

Comment: What should the output be if the input file only has 1 line?

Comment: Because its logs are rotated and are deleted periodically, I just want to see the first line to find out the new time of the log, and the last one is to check what the last error was.

Comment: OK, and again - What should the output be if the input file only has 1 line?

Comment: Oops sorry, I assumed something else and based on that I replied. Your answer: then nothing, the file has only one single line and that is OK. @EdMorton

Comment: So if the input file contains just 1 line then you want no output at all as opposed to that 1 line output once or 2 copies of that line output, right? I don't think any of the answers you currently have would behave that way but I just updated my answer to do so.

Comment: All of the answers, including yours, work fine and perfect for me and I appreciate all of them, including yours again. If the file has only one line, the 'cat'ting it is the only answer. I first use head and tail to see some lines, then I use the below codes to see the only first line (for date) and the last one (for the last error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
sed -n '1p ; $p' error_log
```

`1p` will print the first line and `$p` will print the last line.

As a suggestion, take a look at [info sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), not only `man sed`. You can find the some examples about your question at the paragraph 2.1.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;$b;d' file
```

All sed commands can be prefixed by either an address or a regexp. An address is either a line number or the `$` which represents the last line. If neither an address or a regexp is present, the following command applies to all other lines.

The normal sed cycle, presents each line of input (less its newline) in the pattern space. The sed commands are then applied and the final act of the cycle is to re-attach the newline and print the result.

The `b` command controls command flow; if by itself it jumps out of the following sed commands to the final act of the cycle i.e. where the newline is re-attached and the result printed.

The `d` command deletes the pattern space and since there is nothing to be printed no further processing is executed (including re-attaching the newline and printing the result).

Thus the solution above prints the first line and the last and deletes the rest.

Sed has some command line options, one of which turns of the implicit printing of the result of the pattern space `-n`. The `p` command prints the current state of the pattern space. Thus the dual of the above solution is:

```
sed -n '1p;$p' file
```

N.B. If the input file is only one line the first solution will only print one line whereas the second solution will print the same line twice. Also if more than one file is input both solutions will print the first line of the first file and last line of the last file unless the `-i` option is in place, in which case each file will be amended. The `-s` option replicates this without amending each file but streams the results to stdout as if each file is treated separately.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your new requirement to output nothing if the input file is just 1 line (see [How to find only the first and last line of a file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788721/how-to-find-only-the-first-and-last-line-of-a-file-using-sed/62797227#comment111059986_62788721)):

```
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} {last=$0} END{if (NR>1) print first ORS last}'
```

Original answer:

This is one of those things that you can, at face value, do easily enough in sed:

```
$ seq 3 7
3
4
5
6
7

$ seq 3 7 | sed -n '1p; $p'
3
7
```

but then how to handle edge cases like one line of input is non-obvious, e.g. is this REALLY the correct output:

```
$ printf 'foo\n' | sed -n '1p; $p'
foo
foo
```

or is the correct output just:

```
foo
```

and if the latter, how do you tweak that sed command to produce that output? @potong suggested a GNU sed command:

```
$ printf 'foo\n' | sed '1b;$b;d'
foo
```

which works but may be GNU-only (idk) and more importantly doesn't look much like the command we started with so the tiniest change in requirements meant a complete rewrite using different constructs.

Now, how about if you want to enhance it to, say, only print the first and last line if the file contained `foo`? I expect that'd be another challenging exercise with sed and probably involve non-portable constructs too.

It's just all pointless to learn how to do this with sed when you can use a different tool like awk and do whatever you like in a simple, consistent, portable syntax:

```
$ seq 3 7 |
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} {last=$0} END{print first ORS last}'
3
7

$ printf 'foo\n' |
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} {last=$0} END{print first ORS last}'
foo
foo

$ printf 'foo\n' |
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} {last=$0} END{print first (NR>1 ? ORS last : "")}'
foo

$ printf '3\nfoo\n7\n' |
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} /foo/{f=1} {last=$0} END{if (f) print first (NR>1 ? ORS last : "")}'
3
7

$ printf '3\nbar\n7\n' |
awk 'NR==1{first=$0} /foo/{f=1} {last=$0} END{if (f) print first (NR>1 ? ORS last : "")}'
$
```

Notice that:

1. Every command looks like every other command.
2. A minor change in requirements leads to a minor change in the code, not a complete rewrite.
3. Once you learn how to do any given thing A, how to do similar things B, C, D, etc. just builds on top of the syntax you already used, you don't have to learn a completely different syntax.
4. Each of those commands will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Now, how about if you want to do that for multiple files such as would be created by the following commands?

```
$ seq 3 7 > file1
$ seq 12 25 > file2
```

With awk you can just store the lines in an array for printing in the END:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{first[++cnt]=$0} {last[cnt]=$0}
    END{for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print first[i] ORS last[i]}' file1 file2
3
7
12
25
```

or with GNU awk you can print them from ENDFILE:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{first=$0} {last=$0} ENDFILE{print first ORS last}' file1 file2
3
7
12
25
```

With sed? An exercise left for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

First line:

```
sed '2,$d' error_log
```

Last line:

```
sed '$!d' error_log
```